# Adding Flask on top of a nginx server

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have a cloud server that's being used as a proxy server using an nginx. It's an API server that gets requests from users and redirects those requests to some other URL. Nginx is sufficient to perform such job, but now I want to add an additional feature.

I would like to integrate support to update a remote MongoDB server. To do this, I would like to set up a simple Flask server. My question is, how do I set up a Flask server without affecting the nginx server configuration that I already have now? I have only used Flask with the default primitive webserver that's included in the package so I am not sure how to intergrate it with the nginx server that I have now.

Here's a more detailed plan.

When the user comes to "api.myserver.com" I request to "api.someotherserver.com" and get the response from there. (Nginx does this)

Now, I want to make requests to "api.myserver.com/update_db?username=hello", and update remote MongoDB. (Flask does this)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using nginx to proxy to another server entirely? Or are you running Flask on the same server, and want to use nginx to pass requests to Flask's application server?

Comment: The former is what I am doing right now, and the latter is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to the Flask documentation for this :)

Specifically:

1. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn
2. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups

To implement:

1. Run Gunicorn (I recommend launching it through Supervisord):

   ```
   gunicorn myproject:app
   ```
2. Set up reverse proxying in Nginx:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;

       server_name _;

       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       location / {
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
           proxy_redirect     off;

           proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ooh, beat me to the punch. X)

Comment: can I ask you some followup questions on this? I am not sure how exactly this works. It seems to me if a request is sent to my_api_server everything will be forwarded to the flask server(127.0.0.1) by nginx. What I want is nginx should forward some requests to a third-party server (http://other_host.com) and other requests to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Where it currently says `location /` you can change that and make certain paths sent to a different server. Just copy the location block and change the upstream.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to proxy to whatever application (WSGI) server you're using for Flask. [Gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/) and [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/) are both good picks. Gunicorn gets you off the ground a little faster, uWSGI gives you a little more configurability.

Assuming you already have an nginx instance running at api.myserver.com, you'll need to have something like this in your nginx site config:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass <your app server's bound address or socket>;
}
```

Tweak to fit your setup and requirements, the important bit is [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Now, any requests that get sent to api.myserver.com will get reverse-proxied to the application server that's actually running your Flask instance. Flask will then take care of routes like `update_db` and any parameters. Here's [some good documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) on setting up the WSGI server.